# Dummy / lagged variables and component patterns in regression analysis

Tags: regression, self-study, categorical-data

I've been doing some extra reading for a course I am doing, and I saw this; could someone explain it to me please?

*"A time series may exhibit several component patterns. How does regression with dummy variables differ from regression with lagged variables? How do these 2 approaches deal with these component patterns?"*

Comment: Anybody shed a little bit of light on this for me??